# Is it possible to prevent launching other applications?

Tags: android

I am doing building an application for an app-store market. They gave me following scenario. but I'm not sure it is possible. please give me your advice and suggestions.

This is the scenario:
-User upload his application into this market.
-We wrap that application with our application (I'll explain later).
-Then we will put it in store

More explanation:
This wrapper should bring the ability of buying (daily, monthly and etc.) to the user. If the user had some amount of money in his account then our application should let the user download and launch the game (for example). If user download a game from market and installed it in his device, each time this game is launched we should check his account to see if it has sufficient money. if he didn't have we should prevent launching the application.

I think it is not possible. If a game is installed in a device therefore it is installed. we can't lunch our application when user lunch other games. Am I right? Is there any way to lunch our application any time user clicks other games or applications?

Comment: Amazon appstore certainly does that. If Amazon app is missing, installed apps do not launch. That means they are wrapping it with something. I do not know how is it possible though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes . its possible . use [AIDL][1] .

[1]: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/aidl.html .

write payment related stuffs in payment app .

now whenever any specific game will be launch , use method you created in services using AIDL stub available .

read about AIDL .

Comment: Thanks dear Shailendra, "if the client and service are in separate applications, then the client's application must have a copy of the .aidl file in its src/ directory", by the page you introduced. I read it carefully but i fond that if i want to use AIDL, developer should copy my .aidl file into src/ directory. This is impossible. because we don't want to ask developer to follow our rules. developer just submit his app and we should change something to code.

Comment: its two way communication . if whatever you are looking is possible then i will start to ask money for AngryBirds ...... so the best i think possible is create a library project/Jar and let other app developers  add this .